# I have a warnings and errors with adding Countdown Date in my app. Can someone help me?

Tags: next.js, syntax-error, warnings, countdowntimer, react-tsx

After using Countdown in my project to set the time on the menu, I got errors and warnings called: Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "42" Client: "40", Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>., Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. and react-dom.development.js:16451 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I am doing the project according to the Tutorial and here is the source code (on my side) Thank you very much for anyone who takes the time for me and I am giving the source code below if you want to se the full source code, here is it [text](https://github.com/safak/restaurant-ui)

```
import React from 'react'
import Countdown from 'react-countdown'

const endingDate = new Date("2023-11-30")

const CountDown = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Countdown className='font-bold text-5xl text-yellow-300' date={endingDate} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default CountDown
```

I tried to install Countdown again in different ways, but they didn't help either, and it throws the same thing, for example copying it from the source code, if I didn't do something wrong somewhere, but not like that.